# font-size changes td height if containing an input

Tags: css, html-table, font-size, html-input

having trouble with font-size ; demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9QMky/2/

```
body{
    font-size: 20px;
}
input, div{
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Reading this CSS, I hoped to see the very same dimensions for both input and div in this HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But they do not: the td containing the input is greater.
font-size seems to be a part of the problem, using property

```
display: flex;
```

on the td seems to work. Why?

Note: have played only on Chrome.

Comment: You're using two different tables in the Fiddle.

Comment: Yes the tables are independent, to show the difference (I want the td containing the input acting like the div's td)

Comment: You're forgetting about the default `margin` and `padding` properties. If you try `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` to reset them, you'll get more of what you're looking for.

Comment: That's a point, but not enought: the input's td still have a height too high. Setting font-size to zero seems the main bottleneck. Why?